# Keycloak not logging out the Identity provider after calling the /logout endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect, logout

I'm trying to use Keycloak (13.0.1) as an identity broker. I have an iOS app that uses keycloak to log in via an OIDC identity provider, and then use the token to access a spring-boot backend.

My issue is that I simply can't get the keycloak logout to also log the user out of the Identity Provider session.

I've spent days googling this and looking at both stackoverflow and the keycloak discourse page and git repo, but I couldn't find an answer to my specific issue.

Using the postman to test, the first time I click "Get New Access Token":

[image: using postman to get token]

It successfully redirects me to the identity provider login page (I use the keycloak hint to bypass the initial keycloak login page). Pressing the button again will skip the IDP login and give me the token directly. How convenient, or so I thought...

The problem is that when I use keycloak's /logout endpoint to invalidate the refresh token:
[image: postman logout]

And it successfully returns 204, when I click "Get new access token" again, it skips the login form and gives me the token directly, so there is effectively no way to logout the user and then login with a different user. The only way to bypass this is to manually click the "clear all cookies" button.

Here is my IDP configuration:

[image: IDP config]

Also note that, in the keycloak admin guied it is specified that keycloak should be logging out of the IDPs when a logout is triggered, so it doesn't seem like I should be making any special configs:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#identity-broker-logout

IMPORTANT EDIT:

I marked this question as solved and the solution is correct, but I also needed to turn off the IDP "backchannel logout", because our corporate SSO doesn't like it. Keycloak seems to be able to log out regardless.

Comment: BTW: iOS app can't keep client secret secret, so no client secret should be used. You need public client and `Authorization Code with PKCE`. I would recommend https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/oauth-openid/#what-kind-of-client-are-you-building for more details

Comment: @JanGaraj yeah, I'm using PKCE. The secret is mainly just for me testing with postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It successfully redirects me to the identity provider login page

That redirect is the key. It opens a browser, where Keycloak cookie is created - that is your IdP session. You have to open Keycloak `/logout` endpoint in the same browser, so Keycloak can clear own Keycloak cookies.

Summary: you have to open/redirect (API call doesn't work) user to the same browser to the logout endpoint (API call doesn't work) as you have used for the login. Of course this may not be case for some special flows, but it should be working for standard Authorization Code (with/without PKCE).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but the /logout url for Keycloak requires a POST method, so I'm not sure how I can do that in the browser.

Edit: For clarification, the iOS app developer says that the whole login process opens the safari browser (idk, I'm not an iOS dev), so presumably, that's where the cookies are hidden, so to do what you're suggesting, she would need to somehow send a POST through that browser? She is using AppAuth, if that makes a difference. I'm not sure if that library has a "native" way of handling the logout.

Comment: @MihaiP. IMHO logout is a standard GET request https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/ `For other browser applications, you can redirect the browser to http://auth-server/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=encodedRedirectUri, which logs you out if you have an SSO session with your browser.` Token revocation is a POST request. But logout endpoint != revocation endpoint.

Comment: It works now! Well sort of. I forced postman to use the browser for the OIDC stuff, and then used the logout url from the documentation. Initially it redirected me to an error page that said "Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider", but when I tried to "get new token" again, it makes me re-log in. Woohoo! The error is probably related to a missmatched configuration or redirect url, or maybe our corporate SSO is just bad, but at least it's progress!

Comment: Could you, probably, explain what do you mean by `(I use the keycloak hint to bypass the initial keycloak login page). Pressing the button again will skip the IDP login and give me the token directly.` I would like to skip the IDP login and get the token directly as well.